# PHP What is the date and time every X minutes for the next Y minutes?

Tags: php, windows-10

Windows 10 64-bit. PHP 7.4.1

Does you favorite webpage return data with URLs built around timestamps?  This question is an effort to replicate those URLs with PHP date().

For me the hard part is the jumping off point:

Starting from minutes rounded down to the nearest 10 (19 becomes 10) what will be the year, month, day, hour, minute, and second is always `00` every 10 minutes for 120 minutes? The timestamps are in two formats:

```
032320200030 and 202003230030

mdYHi and YmdHi
```

I like `strtotime`.

```
date('mdYHi', strtotime("+10 minutes"));
date('YmdHi', strtotime("+10 minutes"));
```

but I can't incorporate the jumping off point into it.

```
(floor(date("i") / 10) * 10)
```

Starting from minutes rounded down to the nearest 10 (19 becomes 10).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 10 64-bit. PHP 7.4.1

PHP Starting from floor(date(“i”) / 10) * 10 what will be the date(“Y”), date(“m”), date(“d”), date(“H”), date(“i”) every 10 minutes for 120 minutes at the server returning the data:

```
<?php 
ECHO  "<br />This is ".$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']."<br />"; echo "Timestamp ".date("H:i:s mdy")."<br />";
// $executionStartTime = microtime(true); //measure performance 
// restore leading zero if minutes < than 10.
if (date("i") < "10"){$zfloordate="0".(floor(date("i") / 10) * 10);}else{$zfloordate=(floor(date("i") / 10) * 10);} 
// ob_start(); //output to file to measure performance
echo "the minute is :".date("i")."<br />"; 
echo "the floor minute is: $zfloordate<br />";
// adjust timezone: The server creating the timestamps is in a different timezone (+3). Flooring minute < 10 returns 0. Restore leading zero w/ str_pad. Second is always 00.
$selectedTime = date("YmdH", strtotime("+3 hours")).str_pad((floor(date("i") / 10) * 10), 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT).'00';
$z = DateTime::createFromFormat('YmdHis', $selectedTime);
$zY["00"] = $z->format('YmdHis'); 
for($i = 10; $i <= 110; $i+=10) { 
$z->modify('+10 minutes'); 
$zY["$i"] = $z->format('YmdHis'); 
}
$selectedTime = date("mdYH", strtotime("+3 hours")).str_pad((floor(date("i") / 10) * 10), 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT).'00';
$z = DateTime::createFromFormat('mdYHis', $selectedTime);
$zM["00"] = $z->format('mdYHis'); 
for($i = 10; $i <= 110; $i+=10) { 
$z->modify('+10 minutes'); 
$zM["$i"] = $z->format('mdYHis'); 
} 
echo "<br />";
foreach ($zY as $key => $value){echo "The value at \$zY$key is $value<br />";} 
echo "<br />";
foreach ($zM as $key => $value){echo "The value at \$zM$key is $value<br />";} 
echo "Year-Month-Day-Adjusted Timezone Hour-Minute-Seconds ".date("Y-m-d-H-i-", strtotime("+180 minutes"))."00"."<br />";

// $executionEndTime = microtime(true); //measure performance 
// $seconds = $executionEndTime - $executionStartTime; //measure performance 
// echo "<br />Took $seconds seconds to execute."; //measure performance 
// $htmlStr = ob_get_contents(); //output to file
// ob_end_clean(); //output to file
// file_put_contents("tmp5.txt", $htmlStr); //output to file
?>
```